# Youtube API html5 video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I will be writing an application that uses the youtube API for videos. I want to integrate it with canvas. Is there anyway to make sure I get HTML5 compatible videos through the API calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you mean using `<video />`: the only way to embed YouTube-videos is [`<object />`](http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html) or [`<iframe />`](http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html). So, embedding via `<video />` is not possible at this point and will most likely never be.

In case you mean validity: Both available options are valid in HTML5.

With the IFrame API, YouTube may use HTML video instead of Flash, but this can't be set manually. See [this](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html).

Comment: Thanks that explains it. Guess there is no viable option to use it with Canvas. Thanks!